# (ACX 111) driver problems on Ubuntu server 12.04.4

Tags: networking

This is basically what my wireless card looks to.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
      description: Network controller
      product: ACX 111 54Mbps Wireless Interface
      vendor: Texas Instruments
      physical id: 1
      bus info: pci@0000:05:01.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
      configuration: latency=32
      resources: memory:fbffe000-fbffffff memory:fbfc0000-fbfdffff
```

I've tried many methods to no avail.
As listed 
"ndiswrapper" (to use windows drivers) doesn't work for some reason.
"linksys" driver
"modprobe" to work with ndiswrapper. Broken, reinstalled, still broken.

What in gods earth am I doing wrong?

Also: One of the error messages I'm getting for the linksys
driver; -bash: LSTINDS.new: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are doing anything wrong. A search for *acx111* here and on ubuntuforums.org tells us that there is probably no way at all to get this device going. For whatever reason, there is no interested software maintainer for this fairly uncommon device. Although I always hesitate to solve problems with money, in this instance, I suggest you invest in a newer, supported network card.

Comment: Fair do's, looks like I'm going on Ebay haha.